# Access variables like in MATLAB workspace for C# programs in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, matlab, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, multidimensional-array

My question is very simple but I didn't find any answer so far. I am used to work with MATLAB where everytime it is possible to see the variables in a section called "workspace" and access them in a very intuitive manner (the content being displayed like in a Excel spreadsheet). 
Is it possible to do the same in Visual Studio? E.g. I have a multidimensional array in C# and I want to see its content. At the moment I can just see the content by moving the mouse over the variable name and then a small pop-up window appears. But this way I'm not able to see easily all the elements and, more importantly, I cannot capy the data (if, for example, I want to copy the values of my C# multidimensional array into a speadsheet in order to do some quick check in Excel). Any idea how to do that?

Comment: use rightclick on that object -> add to watch / -> quickwatch

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, there is a "Locals" window where you can see all of the variables in the current scope while debugging.  To get to the window, use the Debug | Windows | Locals menu item.  Unfortunately, this does not display the values like a spreadsheet, but rather in a hierarchical tree.

To copy data from a variable, use the little magnifying glass next to the variable's value and you can change or copy the variable's value.  This is especially useful with long strings.